# how to remove specific tags and keep its content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some unwanted tags inside contenteditable divs and need to remove them.

Those are `&nbsp;` and `span`

Tried with jquery `unwrap` function but but the result is `undefined` because it removes parent's tags and not the tags itself.

Any help? In the example below the expected console is:

```
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('span').unwrap();
  console.log($('#story').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='story' id='story'>
loem ipsum &nbsp;<span style="font-size: 1.3em;">lorem ipsum</span> lorem ipsum
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use like

> $("#story").find("span").contents().unwrap();

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $("#story").find("span").contents().unwrap();
  console.log($('#story').html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='story' id='story'>
loem ipsum &nbsp;<span style="font-size: 1.3em;">lorem ipsum</span> lorem ipsum
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: what about `nbsp`?

Answer (score 1):

You can change `outerHTML` to `innerHTML` for `<span>` and use replace to remove `&nbsp;`

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('span').each(function(){
    this.outerHTML = this.innerHTML;
  })
  let html = $('#story').html();
  $('#story').html(html.replace(/&nbsp;/g,""))
  console.log($('#story').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='story' id='story'>
loem ipsum &nbsp;<span style="font-size: 1.3em;">lorem ipsum</span> lorem ipsum
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unwrap the text nodes, so use [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) method to get all child nodes. And replace `&nbsp;` using [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method where [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method with a callback(the second argument in the callback is old HTML content) can be used for updating the content.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {

  // get span tags child nodes and unwrap
  $('#story span').contents().unwrap();

  // remove &nbsp; from html content
  $('#story').html((_, html) => html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''))

  console.log($('#story').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='story' id='story'>
  loem ipsum &nbsp;<span style="font-size: 1.3em;">lorem ipsum</span> lorem ipsum
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```